# java- obtain full path to file selected by a user for upload

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a simple screen where the file selected for upload by the user is assigned to a file variable.

Google Data APIs have a class "MediaFileSource" which uses "File" to store a file.
Given below is code to assign an image file to a MediaFileSource object.

```
MediaFileSource myMedia = new MediaFileSource(new File("/home/liz/puppies.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
```

What I want to do is, ask the user to specify an image for upload, and then assign that image(chosen by the user using my web app) to the MediaFileSource variable. I just need the full path to that image (which was chosen by the end user) to assign it to a MediaFileSource variable.

What is the best way to do this? I plan to create the above functionality in a java web application on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the full path on the user machine, only the file name.
It's for security reason and its not related to Google App Engine.

Comment: Not only that, but even if you could, you couldn't access it - it's on the user's computer, not on your server.